# Proofs for domains and ranges of relations

Tags: relations

How do I prove/ find counterexamples for the following?

Dom(R∩S)=Dom(R)∩Dom(S)

Rng(R∩S)=Rng(R)∩Rng(S)

Dom(R-S)=Dom(R)-Dom(S)

Rng(R-S)=Rng(R)-Rng(S)

I know how to prove Dom(R∪S)=Dom(R)∪Dom(S)and Dom(R∩S)=Dom(R)∩Dom(S), but am unsure with how to proceed with these. Could someone provide hints/ preliminary steps for each?

I also believe that all are true and can be proven.. is this not the case?

Comment: None of them are true. Look for counterexamples.

Comment: And how did you prove Dom$(R\cap S)=$Dom$(R)\cap$Dom$(S)$?

Comment: I didn't, I proved the statement with ∪, not ∩. Would you mind providing some hints for counterexamples?

Comment: Just try with Dom$(R)$=Condom$(R)$=Dom$(S)$=Condom$(S)$=$\{0,1\}$. There are a limited number of possibilities.

Comment: Note that you only need to consider *either* the domain *or* the converse domain. The result for the other is then just the same result with the converse relations.

Comment: For the second two, wouldn't Dom(R)=Condom(R)=Dom(S)=Condom(S)={0,1} be an example, not a counterexample?

Comment: Dom(0-0)=0-0=0, same goes for Codomain

Comment: Actually came up with some! Thanks!

Comment: Try e.g. $R=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$, $S=\{(0,1),(1,0)\}$.